# Image gallery with max items and pagination with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, pagination

This is my situation:
I have a image gallery with 10 images visible on the main page and a pagination bar. The images came from a for loop iteration over a json file. That's no problem, they are just there ;-)

Something like:
for i=0; i <10; i++
create div with styles and images[i].image;

My question is:
I want to display the next 10 images on page 2, so when you click on page 2, it counts from 11 to 20.
I found the jQuery 'Jpaginate'-plugin...
Can i accomplish that with this plugin?
Could someone explain me in the way i have to thing with Vars, Counts, Objects??

Thanks and kind regards,
Mike

Comment: Try to solve it in my mind and searched google... it's not the language i don't understand but the way of how to think... so i'm looking for the right steps to take, like: build divs with images, click on page 2, destroy images and build with next 10 images... is that the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made you an example on how you can approach this. I'm not saying it is bugproof, but it's the concept that matters. You might find some inspiration and maybe reach your goal.

```js
var imgSrc = "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/36/a5/7b/36a57b0f0ab16e885fcc230addb695c2.jpg";
var json = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++)
  json.push({
    Title: "Title " + (i + 1),
    Source: imgSrc
  });

/*
Just for ease, I'm creating an array with 36 objects (3x3 gallery)
so 9 images per page
*/

var pageLimit = 9;
var page = 1;

showImages();


$("#btnPrevious").click(function() {
  if (pageLimit <= 9) {
    pageLimit = 9;
    page = 1;
  } else {
    page--;
    pageLimit -= 9;
  }
  showImages();
});

$("#btnNext").click(function() {
  if (pageLimit >= json.length) {
    pageLimit = json.length;
  } else {
    page++;
    pageLimit += 9;
  }
  showImages();
});

function showImages() {
  $(".images").empty();
  for (var i = pageLimit - 9; i < pageLimit; i++) {
    var template = $("<div></div>").addClass("template");

    var img = $("<img>");
    img.attr("src", json[i].Source);
    img.attr("alt", json[i].Title);

    var br = $("<br/>");

    var title = $("<span></span>").html(json[i].Title);

    template.append(img).append(br).append(title);

    $(".images").append(template);
  }
  $("#page").html("Page " + page);
}
```

```css
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}
.images {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
img {
  height: auto;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 20px 5px;
}
.template {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="images"></div>
  <button id="btnPrevious">
    &lt; Previous
  </button>
  <span id="page"></span>
  <button id="btnNext">
    &gt; Next
  </button>
</div>
```

Don't mind the CSS, because I suck at that (lol). It was based on the space I had on jsFiddle, but looking at it now (on full page or just the area the snippet provides) it looks awful. If a CSS guru could fix this .. Question in a question?

Comment: Thank you so much for this! And for your time! It's clear to me now, time to develop :-) Wat do you want with your CSS, maybe i can take a look at that ;-)

Comment: Well, I don't really care much about the CSS, it's the code I was focusing on. It's just an example after all, so the style doesn't really matter that much.

Comment: Another way to go at it is by creating all images at page load and work with hide/show. This way you won't have to create objects every time you click a button, but they'll exist on the page and you just have to show 'em.

Comment: That's a great idea. So for example: when i click on page 2, Hide the images in the divs and show the next 10 images??

Comment: Page 1 (1 - 10). Page 2 (11 - 20). Page 3 etc. Just create all images when your page is ready, hide all of 'em by default and show the first 10.

Comment: Great! I'll give it a try. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own pagination  plugin.
You must store current page somewhere and modify your factory.

Something like: for i=current_page * count_per_page; i < count_per_page * (current_page + 1); i++ create div with styles and images[i].image;

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Already on step closer to my goal. Thanks!